# Turtle CLI/Expo iOS build failing: "Please ensure xcode is properly installed"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I am trying to create an iOS build of a React Native app locally using Turtle CLI/Expo. When I run my `turtle: build:ios` command from my React Native project folder I get the following errors:

`turtle[849] ERROR: Please ensure xcode is properly installed`
`err: Error: xcodebuild exited with non-zero code: 1`

`turtle[849] ERROR: Failed to build standalone app`
`err: Error: Tools required to perform standalone app build are missing. Please install them.`

Xcode is definitely installed through the App Store, and I also ran `xcode-select --install` which is telling me it is already installed as well.

Any ideas why Turtle can't seem to detect Xcode?

I am running macOS 12.2 and Xcode 13.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out myself:

I think I had somehow switched to using just the command line version of Xcode whereas Turtle was expecting the full version. I ran the following command to specify using the full Xcode.app and the error was resolved:

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`